# How can the size of an epslatex terminal plot with gnuplottex be altered?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, epslatex

Are there any other options to set the size of a plot with the `epslatex` terminal of `gnuplottex` than the `scale` option?

I noticed that `pgfplots` doesn't have this effect, but for continuity I want all my plots drawn with `gnuplottex`.

My problem is that all the text gets also scaled, which is an unwanted side effect from my point of view.

I suppose I don't have to give a mwe for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could issue a direct gnuplot command as for example `set size 1,0.825`.

Alternatively you can use something along the lines of `\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions={size 6cm,9cm}]`.

Both ways do not change the text size.

Besides that note that the cairolatex terminal avoids eps output which can be nice if you use pdflatex anyway and the tikz terminal, which is possibly the best terminal at the moment, although it slows things down and is problematic with pdflatex due to memory limitations (the memory problems are gone in luatex).

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for! I used `terminaloptions = size` before, but didn't know how to set multiple arguments in it (for the `epslatex` terminal needs `terminaloptions = color` to produce coloured plots).
Just use it like `terminaloptions = {color size xcm,ycm}`! :)